# how create SalesOrders in VtigerCrm use restfulApi

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

im try to use webservice in vtigercrm to create SalesOrders using Postman
to send request to webservice  im use vtigercrm v 7.0 when i try create Products it's done but when i try create SalesOrders fail any one know what the element must send in request or how the request is send in postman 
i use this :
url :.../webservice.php

body {

operation:create

sessionName:

elementType:SalesOrder

element:

```
{
  "salesorder_no": "SO1",
  "subject": "ffff",
  "potential_id": "",
  "customerno": "",
  "quote_id": "",
  "vtiger_purchaseorder": "",
  "contact_id": "",
  "duedate": "",
  "carrier": "",
  "pending": "",
  "sostatus": "Created",
  "txtAdjustment": "0.00000000",
  "salescommission": "0.000",
  "exciseduty": "0.000",
  "hdnGrandTotal": "0.00000000",
  "hdnSubTotal": "0.00000000",
  "hdnTaxType": "group",
  "discount_percent": "",
  "discount_amount": "",
  "hdnS_H_Amount": "0.00000000",
  "account_id": "11x192",
  "assigned_user_id": "19x1",
  "createdtime": "2017-08-17 11:55:51",
  "modifiedtime": "2017-08-17 11:55:51",
  "modifiedby": "19x1",
  "currency_id": "21x1",
  "conversion_rate": "1.000",
  "bill_street": "ddd",
  "ship_street": "dd",
  "bill_city": "",
  "ship_city": "",
  "bill_state": "",
  "ship_state": "",
  "bill_code": "",
  "ship_code": "",
  "bill_country": "",
  "ship_country": "",
  "bill_pobox": "",
  "ship_pobox": "",
  "description": "",
  "terms_conditions": "",
  "enable_recurring": "0",
  "recurring_frequency": "",
  "start_period": "",
  "end_period": "",
  "payment_duration": "",
  "invoicestatus": "c",
  "productid": "14x191",
  "quantity": "1.000",
  "listprice": "0.00000000",
  "comment": "",
  "tax1": "4.500",
  "tax2": "10.000",
  "tax3": "12.500",
  "pre_tax_total": "0.00000000",
  "hdnS_H_Percent": "0",
  "image": "",
  "purchase_cost": "0.00000000",
  "margin": "0.00000000",
  "source": "CRM",
  "starred": "0",
  "tags": "",
  "region_id": "0"
}
```

---

---

but always return

```
{
"success": false,
"error": {
    "code": "MANDATORY_FIELDS_MISSING",
    "message": "Mandatory Fields Missing.."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you all your SalesOrder mandatory fields are in your element array ?

You can find example here :

http://blog.crm-now.de/2015/07/25/samples-for-using-the-crm-interfaces/?lang=en

Comment: sorry i don't understand...you said you succesfully created Products so it's the same way to create SalesOrder

Can you give my clarification?

Comment: I want ceate sales order use api webservice in vtigercrm when I try create product it's successful but when try create salesorders I fail

Comment: The webservice return is explicit. There is à mandatory field missing in your element array

Comment: yes 
I want know what the mandatory field I miss add to array

Comment: Two way to know which mandatory field is missing. First one if you have access to vtiger log, you can check into log file just after the webservice call. Second one you can use the Describe operation through thé webservice and the response give you a description of the SalesOrder module contains an array with the description of each fields.